# Can Hibernate Search implement a Lucene FullTextFilter using embedded collection fields?

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a Hibernate Search entity class that looks something like this:

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
@FullTextFilterDefs({
   @FullTextFilterDef(name="myFilter", impl=MyFilterFactory.class)
})
public class Parent {
   ...
   @Column
   @Field
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany
   @IndexedEmbedded
   private Set<Child> children;
   ...
}
```

The associated enity is likewise straightforward:

```java
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Child {
   ...
   @Column
   @Field
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="children")
   @ContainedIn
   private Set<Parent> parents;
   ...
}
```

If the `MyFilterFactory.getFilter()` method is working with a simple field of `Parent` like this (hardcoded for easier illustration):

```java
...
Term term = new Term("name", "daddy");
Query query = new TermQuery(term);
return new CachingWrapperFilter( new QueryWrapperFilter(query) );
...
```

... then `FullTextQuery`'s with this filter enabled work as expected.

However, if I change the filter to use a field **of an embedded field**:

```java
...
Term term = new Term("children.name", "Junior");
Query query = new TermQuery(term);
return new CachingWrapperFilter( new QueryWrapperFilter(query) );
...
```

... then I get 0 hits every time, despite the fact that the search expression `children.name:parent=junior` works just fine in Luke.

Is there something I am missing here?  Obviously the information is there since I can search it in Luke.  Is there something special you have to do with Hibernate Search to implement a `FullTextFilter` against an embedded field like this, rather than a simple field?

Comment: Well, it seems you are missing an essential part in your example, namely _@Indexed_ on the name fields. Provided that is just an oversight on your side it should really work. If you can reproduce the problem in a unit test I recommend you file an issue here - https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HSEARCH

Comment: Btw, what do you mean with 'children.name:parent=junior works'? This query does not make sense. What's the deal with the parent= part?

Comment: Isn't `@Indexed` only for the class itself?  I already had `@Indexed` on both classes, and I had the associated fields annotated with `@IndexedEmbedded` and `@ContainedI`n, respectively.  However, I neglected to put @Field on the searchable fields, so I've updated the code snippets above.  I'll create a JIRA ticket as soon as I can package up a proper unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While putting together a simple unit test with which to submit a bug ticket, I discovered the real issue.  The problem is not a matter of simple fields vs. complex fields.  The problem was a frustratingly-silly misunderstanding about capitalization.

Normally when Hibernate Search builds a Lucene index, the standard analyzer converts all the field values to lower-case.  When you mostly use the Hibernate Search DSL for queries, you get accustomed to case-insensitivity.  However, when you query using the Lucene API directly, you are responsible for making your search terms lower-case to match the index.

The behavior that I originally saw was due to the case of my search terms.  When I filtered on a simple field, I happened to be using an all-lowercase string.  When I filtered on a complex field, I happened to be using a string with a capital letter.

After making sure that the filter parameter is converted to lower-case, the problem was resolved.

Comment: Correct. When using native Lucene queries one important thing is to apply the same analyzer for the query as for the indexing process. The Search DSL tries to make the right choices for you.